# My new account got deleted after setting notification email to the login-email of the old account

Tags: support, user-accounts

I have made a new account several months ago. Today I have accidentially specified the email address of the old account as the notification email for the new account.

It seems like the two accounts got merged automatically and the new account is lost. Is there a way to undo this?

Comment: Why do you make two accounts in the first place?

Comment: Contact the CM team via the contact us link on the footer and explain the situation. Adding the reason for having two accounts would help.

Comment: @hims056 If I had thought it relevant, I would have deleted the old one.